# Change User Avatar Programmatically in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible to change the user avatar in WordPress programmatically? I'm asking because I'm facing a problem right now in displaying the user avatar in WordPress multisite: the Avatar is not displaying.

Comment: Can you give a bit more information? Do you use the default builtin gravatar? where are they not displaying? What code runs to display them?

Comment: Yes Im using the default built in gravatar in wordpress. They are not displaying on the new site(blog) created by the user in main blog. I use get_avatar() for the display.

Comment: You might try this https://wordpress.org/support/topic/setting-users-avatar-programmatically

Answer (score 4):

I had to do three things to be able to programmatically insert user avatars into my WordPress starting with an avatar that is hosted at a remote URL.

1. Install the [WP User Avatar](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-user-avatar/) plugin.
2. Borrow an upload function from WooCommerce. See below.
3. Adapt some code from a similar [support post](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/setting-users-avatar-programmatically)

Suppose you have a user whose avatar is `$avatar_url = 'http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded&a';`

I use the `upload_product_image()` from WooCommerce's `class-wc-api-products.php` to get the avatar into my local server.

Then, using some of the code from this [support post](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/setting-users-avatar-programmatically), create an attachment. 
Then associate the attachment with the user.

This works only with the WP User Avatar plugin.

```
function se13911452_set_avatar_url($avatar_url, $user_id) {
        global $wpdb;
        $file = upload_product_image($avatar_url);
        $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype($file['file']);
        $attachment = array(
            'guid' => $file['url'],
            'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
            'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename($file['file'])),
            'post_content' => '',
            'post_status' => 'inherit'
        );
        $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $file['file']);
        $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata($attach_id, $file['file']);
        wp_update_attachment_metadata($attach_id, $attach_data);
        update_user_meta($user_id, $wpdb->get_blog_prefix() . 'user_avatar', $attach_id);
    }
```

From [WooCommerce's](http://www.woothemes.com/woocommerce/) [class-wc-api-products.php](https://github.com/justinshreve/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/api/class-wc-api-products.php)

```
/**
 * WooCommerce class-wc-api-products.php
 * See https://github.com/justinshreve/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/api/class-wc-api-products.php
 * Upload image from URL
 *
 * @since 2.2
 * @param string $image_url
 * @return int|WP_Error attachment id
 */
function upload_product_image($image_url) {
    $file_name = basename(current(explode('?', $image_url)));
    $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype($file_name, null);
    $parsed_url = @parse_url($image_url);

    // Check parsed URL
    if(!$parsed_url || !is_array($parsed_url)) {
        throw new WC_API_Exception('woocommerce_api_invalid_product_image', sprintf(__('Invalid URL %s', 'woocommerce'), $image_url), 400);
    }

    // Ensure url is valid
    $image_url = str_replace(' ', '%20', $image_url);

    // Get the file
    $response = wp_safe_remote_get($image_url, array(
        'timeout' => 10
    ));

    if(is_wp_error($response) || 200 !== wp_remote_retrieve_response_code($response)) {
        throw new WC_API_Exception('woocommerce_api_invalid_remote_product_image', sprintf(__('Error getting remote image %s', 'woocommerce'), $image_url), 400);
    }

    // Ensure we have a file name and type
    if(!$wp_filetype['type']) {
        $headers = wp_remote_retrieve_headers($response);
        if(isset($headers['content-disposition']) && strstr($headers['content-disposition'], 'filename=')) {
            $disposition = end(explode('filename=', $headers['content-disposition']));
            $disposition = sanitize_file_name($disposition);
            $file_name = $disposition;
        }
        elseif(isset($headers['content-type']) && strstr($headers['content-type'], 'image/')) {
            $file_name = 'image.' . str_replace('image/', '', $headers['content-type']);
        }
        unset($headers);
    }

    // Upload the file
    $upload = wp_upload_bits($file_name, '', wp_remote_retrieve_body($response));

    if($upload['error']) {
        throw new WC_API_Exception('woocommerce_api_product_image_upload_error', $upload['error'], 400);
    }

    // Get filesize
    $filesize = filesize($upload['file']);

    if(0 == $filesize) {
        @unlink($upload['file']);
        unset($upload);
        throw new WC_API_Exception('woocommerce_api_product_image_upload_file_error', __('Zero size file downloaded', 'woocommerce'), 400);
    }

    unset($response);

    return $upload;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This will works :

```
add_filter('get_avatar_data', 'ht1_change_avatar', 100, 2);

function ht1_change_avatar($args, $id_or_email) {
    if($id_or_email == 1) {
        $args['url'] = 'https://uinames.com/api/photos/female/1.jpg';
    }

    if($id_or_email == 2) {
        $args['url'] = 'https://uinames.com/api/photos/male/19.jpg';
    }

    return $args;
} // end of function
```

If you have avatar dir location metas for users, then use this for all users :

```
add_filter('get_avatar_data', 'ht1_change_avatar', 100, 2);

function ht1_change_avatar($args, $id_or_email) {
    $avatar_url = get_user_meta($id_or_email, 'avatar', true);

    $args['url'] = $avatar_url;

    return $args;
} // end of function
```

Hope you get the point.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely somewhere the `get_avatar` filter is being called and doing something. I recommend searching your plugins and themes for `get_avatar` and looking at things that look like: `add_filter ('get_avatar', .....`

Otherwise, you can write your own behavior with the code below.

```
<?php // in a plugin file or in a theme functions.php
function SO13911452_override_avatar ($avatar_html, $id_or_email, $size, $default, $alt) {
    // check all values

    return $avatar_html
}
add_filter ('get_avatar', 'SO13911452_override_avatar', 10, 5);
```

Comment: Awesome, this was exactly what I needed as I was developing custom plugin with profile widget. So I saved user avatar URL into custom meta and read it in filter function you pointed out to. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

first add author_pic meta to user profile:

```
update_usermeta( $user_id, 'author_pic', trim($_POST['author_pic']) );
```

and add this filter to template function:

```
add_filter('get_avatar_data', 'ow_change_avatar', 100, 2);
function ow_change_avatar($args, $user_data) {
    if(is_object($user_data)){
        $user_id = $user_data->user_id;
    } else{
        $user_id = $user_data;  
    }
    if($user_id){
        $author_pic = get_user_meta($user_id, 'author_pic', true);
        if($author_pic){
            $args['url'] = $author_pic;
        } else {
            $args['url'] = 'registerd user default img url';
        }
    } else {
        $args['url'] = 'guast user img url';
    }
    return $args;
}
```