# How can I change the user's profile picture programatically in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I change the user's profile picture programatically using Wordpress?

Let's say I have a controller, from which I can get the picture's url in my local server.

Here's an example:

```
/user_uploads/avatars/tuser_avt.jpg
```

Tthen I send it to my theme's functions.php to upload it:

```
function uploadAvatar($avatar_url, $email) {

    // upload user's profile picture in gravatar

}
```

I tried to use the wp-user-avatar Wordpress plugin, but to no avail. I read the documentation a couple times and tried different solutions, but I was not able to do it.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-user-avatar/

I also tried some approaches such as:

[Change User Avatar Programmatically in Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13911452/change-user-avatar-programmatically-in-wordpress)

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/setting-users-avatar-programmatically/

Comment: Instead of using Gravatar you just could use a custom field in the user profile for the picture. How about that? Adjust your Theme to use the custom field and you have way more freedom.

Comment: ^^ Definetly the way to create more freedom

Comment: @Blackbam The problem is that I'm using a forum plugin. The goal is to update the profile picture in the user's posts. It uses gravatar.

Comment: If you have no other possibility then using Gravatar then the Gravatar picture is displayed. Maybe you can update it via the API. If you do not want this, do not use Gravatar.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain myself correctly. I don't care if I use Gravatar or not. I just want to change the profile picture. That's all. I assumed the only way was using Gravatar, but if there's another way to do this, I'm fine with it.