# How to set gravatar picture programmatically?

Tags: php, wordpress, gravatar

I'm using gravatar to display my user contact in WordPress but I want to allow them to change their picture. I don't see any way to set it with the API.

I'm not using Woocommerce and I already know to fetch the avatar. Is it possible?

### Edit

After some search, I found in the api documentation, this section : https://fr.gravatar.com/site/implement/xmlrpc/

But I still don't understand how to implement it with my WordPress avatar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change User Avatar Programmatically in Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13911452/change-user-avatar-programmatically-in-wordpress)

Comment: Not at all ! The other discussion talk about how ot get the current avatar. I want to set it ! Plus i'm not using woocommerce !

Comment: Pro tip: I don't have any view as to whether the suggested duplicate is a good fit, but it is given in good faith. It may not matter if that one was tailored to WooCommerce - do read it fully if you can, and treat it as a hint rather than a ready-made solution.

Comment: Hi, I read the topic and it's not a good fit..  I got 3 unlikes for no reasons..

Comment: WIth that in mind, the best approach is to try to work out what those voters had in mind. You have four close votes too, so that is seven people who did not think this is a great question. I would guess people think it is too broad?

Comment: @Efbi, you do realize that the XML-RPC API requires sending the user's password to Gravatar? I.e. You'd have to ask for their Gravatar's password... or their Akismet API key. And [these examples](https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/1403721/Rztpr87i?version=latest) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-user-avatar/ and use their shortcode wherever you want to show the upload picture form just install the plugin and

use

```
echo do_shortcode('[avatar_upload]');
```

It will show the form to upload the picture

Comment: Guys please, the  plugin disable gravatar and use its own way ! I want to use Gravatar !

Answer (score 0):

I think that gravatar not have api to let you update it from external site but maybe there is other solutions to feet your needs.

You can do the following: **let the user add a profile picture directly in your site using a plugin or by developing your own solution**, then check if user has defined his avatar and print it, if not print gravatar or nothing.

There is a lot of plugin to manage avatar, check for example this:

- https://it.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-user-avatar/

For what about the **custom development** you can use for example a form builder like formidable form to let the user upload some image:
Here an example of workflow:

- create a form with file upload with only image format accepted https://formidableforms.com/knowledgebase/file-upload/
- set create post (better if you use custom post type) as form action https://formidableforms.com/knowledgebase/create-posts/
- store the post id in usermeta `add_user_meta( $user_id, 'avatar_id', $theAvatarId);`
- use get_avatar filter to check if there is an avatar stored in usermeta and change the output from gravatar to custom https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/get_avatar

Comment: Well, if users  download their picture  on my server, I lose the benefits of using gravatar... I didnt want to use plugin..